# Accessing the Android Phones SMS and other feature via Data Cable

Tags: sms, remote-control

Is there any way by which I can connect my computer to my HTC Wildfire S and access the SMS (read, compose, delete) without touching the phone? I am looking for something similar but no hope yet.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities to remotely administrate and use an Android Device from your PC -- including, but not restricted to reading/sending SMS. Take a look at the following apps/links:

- [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) is simply to be installed on your Android-Device and can then be accessed via a web-browser ("browser-based"). Manages SMS/MMS, Apps, photos, videos, ringtones...
- [PAW Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.pawserver) has similar features, looks a bit more plain, but adds interesting stuff for developers (you can create your own add-ons, run a webserver with PHP and more)
- [Remote Web Desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rm) can be compared with Airdroid (web-based "virtual Desktop")
- [Phonedeck](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phonedeck.android.cloud) is another alternative, but utilizes the Cloud
- [Droid Phonecontrol](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.neotos.phone2cloud.lite) also involves an "alien server" (routing everything via its authors servers)
- [LazyDroid Web Desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MarcelloAlbano.LazyDroidServer) seems also worth a look
- [Remote My Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidcreation.remotemydroid.lite) is another browser-based management app supporting messaging, browsing the Androids file system, and more
- [WebControl](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=genux.android.webcontrol) offers its browser-based services, including messaging, managing contacts and call history
- if you run windows, [MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client) might be your choice, as it includes all above features plus synchronizing your contacts etc. with your PC, creating backups, and more

I stop here, before the list gets too long -- you see there are plenty of possibilities around :)

Comment: Thank you so much Izzy, MyPhoneExplorer was the best solution for me. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). Not only you can use it to manage SMS but lots of other things like apps, photos, contacts and so on.

You can also use [Mighty Text](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms). With this you don't even have to connect your phone to computer or even leave it at home. This uses the Internet connection of your phone and your browser to send/receive and syns sms messages.